# Socket Programming: How can I read a specified number of bytes from buffer?

Tags: c#, sockets

TCP is stream-based protocol. To convert that stream into my messages, I send the size of each message with the message itself. At server side, I first read the first two bytes of message, which have the size. Then I create a byte array, of size equal to the size which was just read. Then I read the bytes into that array. But for some reason, more bytes are being read than specified. How can I read exactly the same number of bytes as I specify?

Here is my code:

```
while (true)
{
    data = null;
    length = null;

    size = new byte[2];

    handler.Receive(size);

    length += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(size, 0, 2);
    System.Console.WriteLine("Size: " + Int32.Parse(length));

    bufferSize = Int32.Parse(length) + 2;
    bytes = new byte[bufferSize];

    handler.Receive(bytes);

    data += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, bufferSize);
    System.Console.WriteLine("Data: " + data);
}
```

This is my server running in Windows PC, written in C#. My client is running in android phone, written in Java.

Comment: a) why do you use ``length += ...`` instead of ``length = ...``? b) Why the ``+2`` in ``bufferSize = Int32.Parse(length) + 2;``? c) you expect the length to be 2 ascii characters. Does the client send them as 2 bytes? Or maybe a 4 byte integer?

Comment: a) I guess `length += ...` is same as `length = ...` since length is being set to null every time. b) It is to handle newline character sent from client.

Comment: `length` must be `int` not `string`. Maybe you come from `python` or `javascript` worlds.

Comment: `length` is `string`. I'm parsing it to `int` before using as `int`.

Comment: Why are you using strings here? Why not just use `BitConverter` to convert your lengths to/from a `byte[]`? Sending the length as ASCII means you can only send up to 99 bytes per message. Those same two  bytes could, in theory, encode a message size up to 65535 bytes.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Currently, my messages won't exceed even 20 bytes.

Comment: It still seems to be perverse to round trip this information as strings, which was the major part of my consternation. The additional capacity was more of a side note.

Comment: I'll definitely use the approach as advised by you, but first I want to get out of my main problem. The `data` variable contains more bytes than I specified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's unclear why you're adding two to the size that's been transmitted - you've already accounted for the two additional bytes for storing the length during your previous receive. So I'd get rid of the `+2`.

You also need to respect the fact already stated in your question - TCP is a sequence of bytes, not messages. As such, you're never guaranteed whether a call to `Receive` is going to retrieve an entire "message" or just part of one (or, possible, parts of multiple messages). As such, you need to make sure that you respect the *return value* from `Receive`.

We can probably re-write your code as:

```
while (true)
{
    data = null;
    length = null;

    size = ReceiveExactly(handler,2);

    length = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(size, 0, 2); //Why +=?
    bufferSize = Int32.Parse(length); //Why + 2?
    System.Console.WriteLine("Size: " + bufferSize);

    bytes = ReceiveExactly(handler,bufferSize);

    data += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, bufferSize);
    System.Console.WriteLine("Data: " + data);
}
```

Where `ReceiveExactly` is defined something like this:

```
private byte[] ReceiveExactly(Socket handler, int length)
{
   var buffer = new byte[length];
   var receivedLength = 0;
   while(receivedLength < length)
   {
      var nextLength = handler.Receive(buffer,receivedLength,length-receivedLength);
      if(nextLength==0)
      {
         //Throw an exception? Something else?
         //The socket's never going to receive more data
      }
      receivedLength += nextLength;
   }
   return buffer;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

to receive a specific amount of bytes use the method

```
Socket.Receive(Byte[], Int32, Int32, SocketFlags)
```

rather than `Socket.Receive(Byte[])`. see spec [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3xtz6a5%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

I suspect you want something like

```
int len = Socket.Receive(bytes, 0, bufferSize, SocketFlags.None);

data += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, len);
System.Console.WriteLine("Data: " + data);
```

Comment: The first two bytes will have the size of rest of the original message. I convert those bytes to string, then parse that to int. Then I create a buffer of that much size to read the original message in the next receive call.