# C# TCP Framing - How to send the message size

Tags: c#, tcp

This is my code so far.

This is my client:

```
public void Send(string header, Dictionary<string, string> data)
{
    new Thread(() =>
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground = true;
        if (stream.CanRead)
        {
            socketReady = true;
        }

        if (!socketReady)
        {
            return;
        }
        JsonData SendData = new JsonData();
        SendData.header = "1x" + header;
        foreach (var item in data)
        {
            SendData.data.Add(item.Key.ToString(), item.Value.ToString());
        }
        SendData.connectionId = connectionId;

        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(SendData);
        byte[] JsonToBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(json);
        byte[] lengthArray = BitConverter.ToInt32(JsonToBytes, 0);
        stream.Write(lengthArray, 0, lengthArray.Length);
        stream.Write(JsonToBytes, 0, JsonToBytes.Length);
        stream.Flush();



        Debug.Log("Client World:" + json);
    }).Start();
}
```

This is my server:

```
    private void Update()
    {
        //Console.WriteLine("Call");
        if (!serverStarted)
        {
            return;
        }

        foreach (ServerClient c in clients.ToList())
        {
            // Is the client still connected?
            if (!IsConnected(c.tcp))
            {
                c.tcp.Close();
                disconnectList.Add(c);
                Console.WriteLine(c.connectionId + " has disconnected.");
                CharacterLogout(c.connectionId);
                continue;
                //Console.WriteLine("Check for connection?\n");
            }
            else
            {                 
                // Check for message from Client.
                NetworkStream s = c.tcp.GetStream();
                if (s.DataAvailable)
                {
                    string data = c.streamReader.ReadLine();

                    if (data != null)
                    {
                        OnIncomingData(c, data);
                    }

                }
                //continue;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < disconnectList.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            clients.Remove(disconnectList[i]);
            disconnectList.RemoveAt(i);
        }


    }
```

Note that `Update()` is called in `while` loop.

As it is right now i have no TCP message framing. I would like to send the size message to the server and then the server to read until it reaches that size.

However i'm not really sure how this TCP Framing works.
Should i send twice to the server ? First the actual size in bytes and the the message ?

I know that i have to replace this `writer.WriteLine` with `writer.Write` and then on the servers side `c.streamReader.ReadLine();` should be replaced with `c.streamReader.Read();` inserted in `while` loop. I hope i'm on the right way.

Can you please edit my code and add comments to it with explanation so i can understand how this process works ?

Comment: does your json currently stay on one line? (that is usually a configurable option) - if it does, then you are already using *line breaks* as the frames and you shouldn't need to add anything more. If you are using line breaks *in the payload* then indeed you'd need another sentinel value, or length-prefixing. Given that this is text, sentinel values would be more common, and line-breaks are a very popular choice for that

Comment: as a side note: using `ReadLine()` is problematic; a single client could stall your server (maliciously or accidentally) by sending "abc" without a line ending, and then sending nothing more (but keeping the socket open - note that mobile roaming devices are notorious for keeping sockets open even when the actual device is gone) - boom: dead server. A more robust approach is to buffer data as binary, checking *manually* to see if the sentinel value (line-break) is present; only when you have a terminated frame should you try to decode it

Comment: @MarcGravell Wrong use of the protocol will ever result in wrong behavior ;o)

Comment: `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(..., Formatting.None);` will ensure every JSON object is output on a single line. But yes, if you are going to use ReadLine on the server make sure you set ReceiveTimeout on the underlying TcpClient.

Comment: @SirRufo first rule of writing a server: every client is hostile, every client is implementing the protocol incorrectly, and every client will leave an incomplete messa...

Comment: @MarcGravell Sure, but that should be solved by a timeout which will disconnect that session

Comment: OP is posting the same (similar) question multiple times, and all of the above was explained to him multiple times (and I think even by the same people).

Comment: @SirRufo in my opinion (backed up by considerable work in this field), a timeout is the wrong fix there; any time your server code spends waiting for a timeout is time it could have spent doing something useful like servicing requests from well-behaving connections. Some of my servers scale to very high numbers (we're >500k open connections on one, for example - and you're probably at least one of those open connections). Waiting on a timeout isn't an option.

Comment: @Evk you are correct i'm still on the same question but i have never received a full complete answer with examples. All i have so far are comments. I'm very grateful for all the help but still i haven't completed what i'm after.

Comment: @TonyStark nobody is going to write your network code *for you*; your question is pretty vague and is IMO asking the wrong thing - now: I *could* take time to answer the question you've asked, but that would be *actively harmful to you* - because it isn't the right thing *to do*. More specifically: if we assume that you're using line-breaks, what you have *should work* (more or less... see the other feedback); so if it doesn't: ask *about that*, giving details of what happens, etc

Comment: @MarcGravell okey i understand. But still can you point me with examples from where and how to approach ?

Comment: @MarcGravell and why exactly length-prefixing is a wrong thing to do here?

Comment: @MarcGravell How do you know if the client is not sending the frame delimiter (wrong implementation) or is trying to send but the connection is very slow?

Comment: @Evk I'm a big fan of length-prefixing, but the code the OP has currently is text-based and already uses line breaks. They could *add* length prefixes, but they'd probably have to do it in ASCII, presumably using a line-break as a sentinel - that doesn't actually *solve* anything - it just means they have two readlines rather than 1. Sure, they could try to buffer characters up to the known limit, but that's also a huge rewrite. Given the state the code is currently: sticking with the existing line-break approach is probably fine. Ish.

Comment: @SirRufo from a server perspective I don't care. Either they send a valid frame, or they don't. If they don't, I can periodically sweep to kill "probably dead" connections. The only thing I care about is that I never actively *block* on a synchronous method like `ReadLine()`

Comment: @MarcGravell i don't care if it's a big rewrite as long as it is the best approach. I was told that sending the message size at first and then reading the message until it reaches the pre-defined message size at the server is the best approach i can take. I'm i wrong ?

Comment: @MarcGravell since it's a json and not just custom text protocol, line break does not look like the best message terminator (since json with line breaks is still valid json). Of course you could require json on a single line, but still. Sending length as 4 bytes, then sending message (in UTF-8 or something) seems not that bad for me in this case. Plus you can reject big messages without reading. But I see your point - if protocol is text-based you are saying that it's better to have everything else text based too.

Comment: As for the links - there are a lot if you google for 5 minutes. For example: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/04/sample-code-length-prefix-message.html

Comment: @Evk yeah, I'd agree with you in general - I love length-prefixed protocols; but since the OP is using the TextReader API, that is basically a complete rewrite (you can't convince a text reader to not buffer / corrupt your non-text parts). I'm not saying that (the rewrite) is necessarily a bad idea...

Comment: Do you say that if i want my message to be `json` i can not create a lenght-prefixed ?

Comment: If i prefix the message like this: https://pastebin.com/2GAPzpnd to put the size of the string in bytes before the message. Can i be sure that bytes length will be always the same so i'll know to read the first X characters to get how big is the actual size of the following string ? If so that mean i can use `WriteLine` but on the server i have to use `Read` ?

Comment: I have updated my question can you please check if like this i'm prefixing the message size correctly. I mean is this a correct approach how does it look to you. Do you suggest different approach ?

Comment: In addition to what the people above are suggesting, I'd go with my fail-safe approach to advising people who try to invent their own protocol: **don't**. By the time you've read enough about how networks, sockets and protocols work (see: Tanenbaum, Beej), you're sure that you don't want to go through the same hell again as thousands of developers before you, and you use a ready-made solution. I'm surprised @Marc hasn't suggested [protobuf-net](https://github.com/mgravell/protobuf-net) yet. This is also your sixth question about the same subject, I'd suggest to take a step back and rethink.

Comment: @CodeCaster meh, they already have a serializer - JSON; now sure, there are ways to make pb-net work nicely as part of the framing (*WithLengthPrefix, etc), but that doesn't *by itself* lend itself to a good server - you need additional things server-side, and those things tend to be similar between any format.

Comment: Can you check my updated question about the `Send` function from the client. Do you think it's a good approach ?

Comment: @Marc true, apart from the serialization component you still need a framing and reassembling component; I skipped over that.

Comment: @TonyStark `toBytes` and `JsonToBytes` appear to be the same thing; why are you sending it twice?

Comment: @MarcGravell i have updated the question with code modification. I'm not sure i'm doing it right.

Comment: @TonyStark well that won't compile (byteArray isn't declared, and lengthArray isn't an array), so: no. It looks like you're trying to do a binary length prefix. That's not a bad idea, but it will require significant server-side changes. You're probably looking for `byte[] BitConvert.GetBytes(int)`, btw

Comment: I have updated the question again. Does it look okey now ?

Comment: @TonyStark no; you mean `JsonToBytes.Length`, but : why are you asking us? **does it produce the right output?**

Comment: I have updated again. I saw it after i wrote the comment. Is it okey now ?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a replacement for compiling, running, testing and debugging your own code. If you prefix your messages with the bytes of an int32 representing their length (hint: `BitConverter.ToInt32(JsonToBytes, 0)` doesn't do that), then you can't correctly read the messages' length with a StreamReader.

Comment: My question is how now i should read this at the servers side? Let's assume everything on the client is okey but i have no idea how to read it at the server's side.

Comment: Read four bytes, reconstruct the length int from that, then read as many bytes as that int indicates, rinse and repeat.

Comment: See also [Socket Programming: How can I read a specified number of bytes from buffer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36714041/socket-programming-how-can-i-read-a-specified-number-of-bytes-from-buffer)

Comment: Is `stream.Write` correct or i should use `writter.Write` ?