# How do I stop using too much CPU in my async loop?

Tags: c#

I have a basic `TcpListener` server that accepts `TcpClient` requests and sticks them in separate threads.

The server thread that accepts requests uses `await _server.AcceptTcpClientAsync()` so it returns cpu resources and doesn't use any cpu until it gets a client request.

My client loop calls `await client.GetStream().ReadAsync` but that's wrapped in a `if (client.Connected && client.Available > 0)` so if there is no data it just returns null, so nothing is being awaited.

The options I know of are to add a `Thread.Sleep` which is bad practice and will slow down my apps, use a `EventWaitHandle` but I'd have to know set that somehow or to remove the `if (client.Connected && client.Available > 0)` check, which would sit indefinitely waiting for data, so if the server went down the program would effectively be dead.

EDIT: Added client code

```
public class TcpServer
{
    private TcpListener _server;
    private bool _isRunning;
    private object _lock = new object();

    // Listener thread
    public async void StartServer()
    {
        _server = new TcpListener("127.0.0.1", 1234);
        _server.Start();
        _isRunning = true;

        Thread.CurrentThread.Name = "TcpServer";

        while (_isRunning)
        {
            // Block until client connection
            TcpClient newClient = await _server.AcceptTcpClientAsync();

            // Create a thread to handle client connection
            new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(HandleClientConnection)).Start(newClient);
        }
    }

    // Client Thread
    public async void HandleClientConnection(object obj)
    {
        // Create worker object
        var client = (TcpClient)obj;
        {
            ClientId = Guid.NewGuid()
        };

        // Read client data
        while (client.Connected)
        {
            var msg = await client.ReadMessageAsync();
        }

        // Disconnected
    }
}

// Read data from stream when available. Used on server and client
public static async Task<Message> ReadMessageAsync(this TcpClient client)
{
    if (client.Connected && client.Available > 0)
    {
        int totalBytesRead = 0;
        var data = new byte[client.Available];

        while (totalBytesRead < client.Available)
        {
            totalBytesRead += await client.GetStream().ReadAsync(data, 0, client.Available);
        }

        return BinarySerializer.DeserializeMessage(data) as Message;
    }

    return null;
}

// Client Code
public async Task Start()
{
    ConnectToServer();

    while (_isRunning)
    {
        // Reconnect to server if needed.
        if (!_tcpClient.Connected)
        {
            ConnectToServer();
        }

        // Wait for messages
        var message = await _tcpClient.ReadMessageAsync();
        HandleMessage(message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `ReadMessageAsync` *wait* until a message has been received then?

Comment: You could use a timer to periodically check.

Comment: So when you profiled the application where was it spending its CPU time?

Comment: You can completely ditch the `if` condition and all the checks for available bytes.

Comment: Read operations do not return until they have *something* to return. If you ever get *nothing* from the read operation then the client has disconnected.

Comment: The reason for the high CPU usage is that your program spends most of it's time in the loop checking if there is data available - completely unneccessarily I want to add. That's called polling and is bad practice.

Comment: As said above - you need to completely remove that `Available` check. And if you have some doubts and think it's necessary - you need to explain why you think so.

Comment: One more thing: TCP is **Stream** based, you can't just shove serialized messages down that pipe and expect them to arrive in one piece (or only one at a time) - you need to come up with a control mechanism/protocol.

Comment: Shouldn't the client be using [`ConnectAsync()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh138320(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: @MatthewWatson I don't see any client-side code in this question.

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer @Evk When I remove the checks it throws exceptions when trying to deserialize data[] which is empty. How can I rewrite the `ReadMessageAsync` method to be more robust?

Comment: @MatthewWatson OP has been updated with client code

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer ` you can't just shove serialized messages down that pipe and expect them to arrive in one piece` This is something I worried about but seems to work ok, at least for now, with several clients. I was hoping to create an object that I can serialize/deserialize instead of using strings for everything. What's best practice on how to accomplish this?

Comment: @user3953989 My usual approach would be like this: Build the entire message you want to send so you know it's size (in bytes). Use `BitConverter` to convert that length into a bytearray (eg Int32 = 4 Bytes) and send that array first. On the other side call the `Read` (or ReadAsync) method with a length of 4 (and convert the result back to int). Now you know the length of the message and can call `Read` again with the length of the actual data. Call `Read` in a loop with a length of *Expected length of data*.

Comment: Decrement that expected length by the amount of received bytes until you have the entire message (Kind of like you do now to keep track of the message length). After that - begin reading the length of the next message again. After each `Read` you should check if you received 0 bytes - that means the client disconnected.

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer That makes sense and I've seen similar code on GitHub but how would you know those 4 bytes read are the header of a new message and not the middle of some other message since the order isn't guaranteed?

Comment: @user3953989 Tcp guarantees that bytes are received in the same order they are sent, just not all at once. If you want to make sure (e.g. in a multithreaded application) you don't mix in some unwanted data, you can use a `lock` or send the entire message including the length header with a single call to `Send`.

Comment: One more thing: For now you can probably ignore this but keep in mind that when you serialize data (e.g. the length with BitConverter) that the byte order can be reversed depending on the endianess. Fortunately `BitConverter` has a property that you can check which endiness you are working with (I think BitConverter.IsLittleEndian or so) On the same computer it will always be the same, across computers it *can* be different.

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer Could you provide example code or a link to some articles with code I can research? It sounds like there's a lot of points I need to understand to rewrite my code. Thanks

Comment: Uhm ... not really no. Most tutorials are either incomplete or really bad. The best approach in this case might actually be "learning by doing".

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer I believe most of those really bad ones are the ones I've gathered knowledge from lol. I'll research all the helpful info you've posted. Thanks again!

Comment: I've tried to find a link but surprisingly in 15 minutes didn't find a single article implementing reading from tcp socket correctly. However, there are multiple stackoverflow questions covering that.

Comment: @Evk Thank you for researching. I've hit up the 1st several pages of SO and found this gem that at least helps my message delivery https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41718342/async-socket-client-using-tcpclient-class-c-sharp

Comment: That's good, but still doesn't show how to read correctly. Here is a sample of correct read: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36739583/5311735 (ReceiveExactly function, it's for socket but easy to adapt for network stream).